# Algorithm for coloring a hexagon tile map with minimum distance (3) for reoccurring colors

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, tile, hexagonal-tiles

I need to create a hex-tile map, using at most 19 colors, where each color must keep a distance of at least 3 tiles. However, I do not need to use all 19 colors. If there exists an algorithm that solves this distance constraint with less than 19 colors, this is completely fine.

The Beckman-Quarles theorem [1] looks related, and there is a 7-color tile map shown where same colored tiles keep a distance of 2 to each other.

But I have a hard time to find an understandable description or even implementation for constructing a hex tile map with a distance of 3.

[1] http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satz_von_Beckman_und_Quarles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's set up a coordinate system where the hex with coordinates `(i,j)` is adjacent to `(i-1,j), (i-1,j+1), (i,j-1), (i,j+1), (i+1,j-1), (i+1,j)`.

```
(0,3)       (2,2)       (4,1)
      (1,2)       (3,1)
(0,2)       (2,1)       (4,0)
      (1,1)       (3,0)
(0,1)       (2,0)
      (1,0)
(0,0)
```

I'm going to apply a shear transform so that I can draw hex grids compactly with ASCII art. The transformed 7-hex region looks like this.

```
**
***
 **
```

What you want to do is tile the plane with the following 19-color layout.

```
ABC
DEFG
HIJKL
 MNOP
  QRS
```

The tiles can fit together like so.

```
   111
   1111
00011-11
00001111333
00-001113333
 000022233-33
  00022223333555
     22-223335555
      222244455-55
       22244445555
          44-44555
           4444
            444
```

I've marked the tile centers with `-`. These form a lattice generated by two vectors: `(5,-3)` and `(3,2)`. Given hex coordinates `(i,j)`, we can (inelegantly, perhaps) solve the matrix equation

```
[5 -3] [u]   [i]
[3  2] [v] = [j]
```

in rational variables `u, v`, then, trying all four integer roundings of `u` and `v` to nearby integers `u*` and `v*` respectively, determine which tile `(i,j)` lies in and apply the appropriate color, where the tile center is

```
[5 -3] [u*]
[3  2] [v*].
```

Comment: What do you mean with "What you want to do is tile the plane with the following 19-color layout"?

Comment: @benjist Each of the capital letters represents a colored hex. I want to replicate that 19-hex pattern across the plane in a regular fashion.

Comment: What I forgot to mention: All sides of the hex must be equal. The hex represents a simplified circular region in my case (this makes a difference when fitting the tiles together). Or maybe I misinterpreted your suggestion?

Comment: @benjist The ASCII art is a schematic, not geometric illustration. Each letter represents a hex. The adjacent hexes are above left, above, left, right, below, below right.

Comment: What I mean is that if you use make a single hexagon made of 19 small hexagons, it won't fit on a map without having to shift. Or alternatively you leave a single buffer hexagon space between each two large hexagons you put as pattern on a map.

Comment: I made a quick illustration: http://imgur.com/2jB8qXR Sorry for the bad color scheme. You can't pu another large hexagon below the one in the middle (because it would need 4 small hexagons on top), unless you shift the hexagons. But if we shift the hexagons we can't simply fill the map using a pattern with large hexes.

Comment: @benjist Unlike the diagram, the tiling that I have in mind is not axis aligned.

Comment: That makes the construction a bit more difficult for what I need to implement it for - but this is the best solution. Great, thanks for your help!